# C++ Convert Lat Long to BNG with Proj.4

Tags: coordinate-system, c++, proj, visual-c++

Im creating a plugin for VBS2. In the program I can output a grid in either LAT LONG,UTM or MGRS. I need to be able to convert to BNG. I have managed to create a TKinter application in python that works using Proj.4 but now need to create it in C++ as a DLL.

The LatLong im using (51.20650N 1.81906W) is a known point, the BNG conversion is approx SU 127 452.

```
#include <proj_api.h>




double x = 51.20650; //atof(GetStrArgument(input, 0)); 
double y = 1.81906;  //atof(GetStrArgument(input, 1));  

char *pj_latlongc = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84";
char *pj_UTMc = "+proj=utm +zone=29 +ellps=WGS84";
char *osc = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000    +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";

projPJ pj_OS = pj_init_plus(osc);
projPJ pj_UTM = pj_init_plus(pj_UTMc);
projPJ pj_latlong = pj_init_plus(pj_latlongc);

x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
y *= DEG_TO_RAD;

int p = pj_transform(pj_latlong, pj_OS, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL);
```

Unfortunately the result is completely wrong and doesn't make sense.Could someone help on this?